# C# How can I loop through a list string and compare values

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and have a project where I have a List String and have to filter some images out with certain extensions . This is my code

```
// App Config
<add key="FilterImages" value=".jpg ,.gif"/>

List<string> _FilterList = new List<string>();
string[] FilterList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilterImages"].ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string s in FilterList)
{
    _FilterList.Add(s.Trim().ToLower());
}

var files = newFiles.ListDirectory(".");
foreach (var f in files)
{
    // Here new files come and I can get the file names using
    // f.name ... How can I check for correct extension here   
}
```

Inside the ForEach loop I would like to use **_FilterList** and check the file extension of the new files coming in . I can get the file names using **f.Name** any suggestions would be great

Comment: See [Path.GetExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can factorize your code using LinQ to :

```
var _FilterList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilterImages"].ToString()
     .Split(',')
     .Select(p => p.Trim().ToLower())
     .ToList();

var files = newFiles.ListDirectory(".");
```

And getting Filtered files path with :

```
var acceptedFiles = files.Where(p => _FilterList.Any(l => p.Contains(l)).ToList();
var unAcceptedFiles = files.Where(p => !_FilterList.Any(l => p.Contains(l)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try some thing like this , Just look for file extension in your `FilterList`.
This may not compile but its an idea how to look for valid file extension.

```
foreach (var f in files)
{
    if(_FilterList.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f.FileName))
    {
       //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Or you can use Linq

```
 var allowedFiles =  files.Where(p => _FilterList.Any(l => p.Contains(l)).ToList();
```

Comment: Would have been my solution too. However there are some caveeats: Case Sensitivty is a thing. And as foreach uses a Enumerator under the hood, you can not modify the collection. So 'your stuff' can not be a Remove operation on files.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's obtain extensions to be filtered out; `HashSet<string>` seems to be a better collection fo this

```
HashSet<string> extensions = new HashSet<string>(ConfigurationManager
    .AppSettings["FilterImages"].ToString()
    .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(item => item.Trim()), 
  StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // ".GIF" should be treated as ".gif"
```

Then we can start checking `files`:

```
var files = newFiles.ListDirectory(".");

foreach (var f in files) {
  // if "f" is FileInfo we can use f.FullName
  // if "f" is string then put just f, not f.FullName 
  if (extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f.FullName))) {
    // file has a correct extension 
  } 
}
```